# Want to add a directory prior to bind querystring in postbackurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, query-string

Currently I have this.. which works fine

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Width="80" Height="60" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("Invno")%>' />
```

However, the database is hard coded to pull "/item.aspx?innvo=1234"

I need however to put a sub directory in there first, so "/test/item.aspx?innvo=1234"

I can not change the hard coding in the table as it effects other things.

So I just need to know how to put the /test/ in there as everything I have tried fails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Width="80" Height="60" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#"/test" + Eval("Invno")%>' />
```

or

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Width="80" Height="60" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("Invno","/test{0}")%>' />
```

Comment: Sweet that first one worked! Just had to add a / after the word test as well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Width="80" Height="60" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>' PostBackUrl='/test<%#Eval("Invno")%>' />
```

Comment: when I do this I get /test%3C%Eval("Invno")%> instead of the result

Comment: You can also try something like PostBackUrl='<%# MyMethod(Eval("Invno"))%>', where MyMethod is a method you create in code behind and where you append the /test string.